# Operator overloading in C#

Tags: c#

I was a bit confused with Operator overloading in C# language, Can you Please tell me is Operator overloading static or dynamic in nature.

Answer (score 11):

If you mean "is it polymorphic or not?" then the answer is no - operators are found statically by the C# compiler, unless you're using the `dynamic` type. For example, consider this code:

```
using System;

class Test
{    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string x = "hello";
        string y = new string(x.ToCharArray());        
        Console.WriteLine(x == y); // True

        object ox = x;
        object oy = y;
        Console.WriteLine(ox == oy); // False

        dynamic dx = x;
        dynamic dy = y;
        Console.WriteLine(dx == dy); // True
    }
}
```

The first call to `==` uses the operator declared in `string`, as the compiler knows that both operands are of type `string`. It compares the two character sequences, finds they're equal, and returns True.

The second call to `==` uses the operator declared in `object` because the compile-time types of the expressions `ox` and `oy` are `object`. This operator only compares references. The references are different (they refer to different values), so this returns False. Note that in this case the *values* of `ox` and `oy` will refer to strings at execution time, but that *isn't* taken into account when the compiler decides which overload to call. (It *only* knows of `ox` and `oy` as being of type `object`.)

The third call to `==` uses dynamic typing to discover the operator at execution time, using the *actual* types of the references, rather than the compile-time types of the expressions. This discovers the overload in `string`, and so again the operator returns True.

Answer (score 0):

The basic Operator Overloading is static:

```
public static SomeClass operator ++(SomeClass arg)
```

Try [this Series](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-operator-overloading-the-crazy-side-part-1) showing some examples