# What does operator + in method definition do?

Tags: c#, .net, operator-overloading

So I have never seen this before and I'm trying to figure out what it does:

```
public static MyFunction operator +(MyObject first, MyObject second)
```

Comment: It's an operator overload: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: It's the addition operator. It allows you to "add" two `MyObjects`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operator overloading in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899339/operator-overloading-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Thanks I actually figured it out after I asked the question. I just have never seen it used before so it threw me off and the overload in this code base was insane.

Comment: If you want to have an extended discussion about site moderation policies, please take that up on Meta or a chatroom. I've cleaned up the comments to focus on the question asked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is called an [operator overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

It allows you to use primitive operators such as `+`, `-`, `%`, etc. to apply to objects you define.

An example where it might be useful is if you have two Lists and you want to add one to the end of the other.  Another example used by MSDN is if you have complex numbers with two vectors.

These days it is generally more appropriate just to define a method that takes in the number of operands you want to apply and use that method, rather than make your code more difficult to read and debug by overriding an operator that is used for other things.

**tl;dr; use methods instead of operator overloading unless you have a damn good reason.**

Comment: `vector1 + vector2` > `Vector.Add(vector1, vector2)`

Comment: @EmperorAiman Generally, operator overloading should be avoided unless you are writing some really core framework stuff IMO.  Do what you want, but it's just a method under the hood and you can avoid confusion if you just use a method signature

Answer (score 7):

It overrides the `+` operator for that class, allowing code like this to compile and run:

```
MyObject op1 = new MyObject();
MyObject op2 = new MyObject();
MyFunction result = op1 + op2;
```

Doing the `+` operation invokes the method you posted. For more on operator overloading, see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It's called operator overloading, and allows you to define a behaviour for operators like '+', '-', '==', etc.

See here for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx